# Error with QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I am having build errors with QT Creator and I was wondering if someone knows why its making these errors. Thanks

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    //Create Scene
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();

    //Creat Item To Put Into Scene
    QGraphicsRectItem * rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
    rect->setRect(100, 50, 100, 100);

    //Add Item To Scene aka buffer
    scene->addItem(rect);

    //add a view
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mygame.pro:**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-05-03T12:14:31
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mygame
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  +=
```

**Compile Output:**

```
Error while building/deploying project mygame (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

I am not sure what is making these errors(words words and more words for more detail so "It looks like your post needs some more detail" will go away... its not going away so I shall continue typing until it chooses to do so but it looks like it is not going to any time soon. there we go).

Comment: That's not a very helpful question title.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Compile Output tab.  If needed you can also run qmake on the command prompt.

Another helpful way to fix bizarre qmake errors is to get a fresh Project settings in Qt Creator.

Close Qt Creator, delete the .pro.user file, and reopen Qt Creator with your project. This will force you to reconfigure your project with your Qt Version(s) Debug/Release, etc.

Hope that helps.